# How to sign commits from dev container?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, github, gnupg, vscode-devcontainer

I tried following the steps here: https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/sharing-git-credentials#_sharing-gpg-keys

But when trying to make a git commit inside the container, I get this error:

```
error: gpg failed to sign the data:
gpg: skipped "***": No secret key
[GNUPG:] INV_SGNR *******
[GNUPG:] FAILURE sign ****
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
```

Signing works fine on my local (Mac) machine. I followed Github docs (https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification) to create the GPG key.

Comment: it seems likely that you only imported the public key.